# What is the equation for multivariate kernel density estimation techniques?

Tags: machine-learning, kernel-density, multivariate-testing

I was reading about non-parametric kernel density estimation. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation

For uni-variate where D = 1, we can write like

[image]

**For Multivariate Kernel density estimation (KDE), more preciously for d=3 and X = (x,y,z) can we write:**

[image]

Is this technically correct? Can any one help with this?

Comment: This is perhaps better suited on another SE site.  Maybe [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) (since it's more of a "whiteboard" question).

Comment: Since this is about the formula and not any specific algorithm solving the formula, math.SE seems like the better migration target to me.

Comment: My guess would be [Theoretical Computer Science](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30717822/what-is-the-equation-for-multivariate-kernel-density-estimation-techniques#comment49493711_30717822), not Math.SE.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be migrated, probably to math.stackexchange.com, possibly programmers.stackexchange.com if it's really a request for an algorithm rather than an equation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be on Theoretical Computer Science stack exchange

Answer (score 2):

This is very difficult to do on your own, and you really should do this through some package. Nevertheless, the definition [is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_kernel_density_estimation#Definition):

*f<sub>H</sub>(x)= 1 / n \sum<sub>{i=1}</sub><sup>n</sup> K<sub>H</sub> (x - x<sub>i</sub>)*, where

- x = (x1, x2, …, xd)T, xi = (xi1, xi2, …, xid)T, i = 1, 2, …, n are d-vectors;
- H is the bandwidth (or smoothing) d×d matrix which is symmetric and positive definite;
- K is the kernel function which is a symmetric multivariate density;
- KH(x) = |H|−1/n K(H−1/2x).

Comment: im planning to do it in python. i already tried for 1D / where d =1, but I need it for 3D data.. here what I tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30696741/how-to-implement-kernel-density-estimation-in-multivariate-3d
any idea?

Comment: How about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21918529/multivariate-kernel-density-estimation-in-python)? Sorry, but you really should not (re)implement this on your own, IMHO.

Comment: yeah you are absolutely right, but i was trying to get the intuition of KDE in 3D. i was reading this page http://goo.gl/UcIjmh (section EXAMPLE 3.3). They have shown equation for 2D. Could you please help me to write that for 3D or is my one correct ?

Comment: Not today, sorry. When I have more time.